# Showing that the Witt algebra $W(1)$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{k})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

As the title suggests, I need to show that the Witt algebra $W(1)$ with basis $\{e_i \, | \, -1 \leq i \leq p-2\}$ where $e_k=t^{k+1}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}$ with Lie bracket defined by

$$[e_i,e_j]=(j-i)e_{i+j} \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, i+j \leq p-2$$
$$[e_i,e_j]=0 \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, i+j \geq p-1,$$

is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{k})$ with basis $\{e,h,f\}$ with Lie brackets defined as

$$[h,e]=2e, \,\,[e,f]=h, \,\,[h,f]=-2f.$$

Now take $\mathrm{char}(\mathbb{k})=p=3$. The basis for $W(1)$ is then $\{e_{-1},e_0,e_1\}$ and the Lie brackets are

$$[e_0,e_{-1}]=-e_{-1}, \,\, [e_{-1},e_1]=2e_0, \,\,[e_0,e_1]=e_1.$$

I began by defining a linear map $\varphi: \mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb{k}) \rightarrow W(1)$ by

$$\varphi(e)=e_{-1}, \,\, \varphi(h)=e_0, \,\, \varphi(f)=e_1.$$

I then looked at $\varphi([e,h])=\varphi(-2e)=-2e_{-1}$. But this is not equal to $[\varphi(e),\varphi(h)]=[e_{-1},e_0]=e_{-1}$ and so clearly this map is not isomorphic. I'm unsure what map I need to use to show the two Lie algebras are isomorphic, could anyone give me any advice?

Comment: Yes, I have computed the isomorphism, and can show it to you. You can try yourself with $\phi(e)=x_1e_{-1}+x_2e_0+x_3e_1$ etc. and determine conditions for the unknowns $x_i$.

Comment: Are you saying to then also take $\varphi(h)=y_1e_{-1}+y_2e_0+y_3e_1$ and similarly for $\varphi(f)$ and then solve using the definition of homomorphism, i.e. $\varphi([x,y])=[\varphi(x),\varphi(y)]$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Furthermore the determinant of $\phi$ must be nonzero, too.

Comment: I'm confused as I end up with 

$$\phi(e)=x_1e_{-1}+x_2e_0+x_3e_1$$
$$\phi(h)=y_1e_{-1}+y_2e_0+y_3e_1$$
$$\phi(f)=z_1e_{-1}+z_2e_0+z_3e_1$$

and taking the Lie brackets of these seems extremely long, have I misunderstood what you meant?

Comment: I got there in the end, thanks for your help!